# How do I explicitly pass my authentication key into Google's text to speech engine?

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Google Cloud's text to speech engine for my robot, and I cannot understand the reference page for passing the key explicitly in Python as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

I spent several hours yesterday exploring different options on how to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` needed for implicit authorization including an `export` command in the shell script I use to start the robot, using `os.environ` commands in Python, and using `os.system` to call an `export` command.

```py
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

voice = robot_config.get('google_cloud', 'voice')
keyFile = robot_config.get('google_cloud', 'key_file')
hwNum = robot_config.getint('tts', 'hw_num')
languageCode = robot_config.get('google_cloud', 'language_code')

voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    name=voice,
    language_code=languageCode
)

audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
    audio_config=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
)

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = keyFile
```

Logging in via SSH shows that I have successfully set the environment variable since it shows up in `env`; however a `DefaultCredentialsError` is thrown with the following message

> Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, pease see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Logging in and setting the environment variable manually will allow the script to run and work, but this is not a long term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer lies in the `google.oath2` library. The `client` object is not looking for a json key, and is instead looking for a service account object.

```py
from google.oath2 import service_account
from google.cloud import texttospeech

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient(
    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(keyFile)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for  me:

```
import os
from google.cloud import texttospeech

os.environ ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= "/home/pi/projectx-17f8348743.json"

client=texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
```